# Why do useragents specify 64-bit?

Tags: user-agent

Why does the useragent include this information? I can't see why a website would need to know.

For example:

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux **x86_64**) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/11.0.696.28 Chrome/11.0.696.28 Safari/534.24

Both Firefox and Chromium on Ubuntu do this.

Comment: I think only linux does this because this is my windows useragent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.204 Safari/534.16

Comment: So the web server knows to serve 64-bit images. Duh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This information, when available, is often used by websites to decide which software to recommend you download.  If it detects that you have a 64-bit system then it can recommend that you download the 64-bit version of their software.

It is purely down to the useragent (and to some extent the operating system) as to whether it provides this information to the website.